# How does "Assignment Branch Condition size for index is too high" work?

Tags: ruby, code-metrics, rubocop

Rubocop is always report the error:

> app/controllers/account_controller.rb:5:3: C: Assignment Branch Condition size for index is too high. [30.95/24]

```
if params[:role]
  @users = @search.result.where(:role => params[:role])
elsif params[:q] && params[:q][:s].include?('count')
  @users = @search.result.order(params[:q][:s])
else
  @users = @search.result
end
```

How to fix it? Anyone has good idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [ABC size <sup>[1]</sup>](http://archive.is/5LBqQ)[<sup>[2]</sup>](https://hub.codebeat.co/docs/software-quality-metrics#assignment-branch-condition) is

> computed by counting the number of assignments, branches and conditions for a section of code. The counting rules in the original C++ Report article were specifically for the C, C++ and Java languages.

The previous links details what counts for A, B, and C.  ABC size is a scalar magnitude, reminiscent of a triangulated relationship:

```
|ABC| = sqrt((A*A)+(B*B)+(C*C))
```

Actually, a quick google on the error shows that the first indexed page is [the Rubocop docs for the method that renders that message](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.27.0/RuboCop/Cop/Metrics/AbcSize).

Your repo or analysis tool will define a threshold amount when the warning is triggered.

### Calculating, if you like self-inflicting....

Your code calcs as

```
(1+1+1)^2  + 
(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)^2   + 
(1+1+1+1)^2 
=> 194
```

That's a 'blind' calculation with values I've made up (`1`s).  However, you can see that the error states numbers that probably now make sense as your ABC and the threshold:

```
 [30.95/24]
```

So cop threshold is `24` and your `ABC size` is `30.95`.  This tells us that the rubocop engine assign different numbers for A, B, and C.  As well, different kinds or Assignments (or B or C) could have different values, too.  E.G. a 'normal' assignment `x = y` is perhaps scored lower than a chained assignment `x = y = z = r`.

### tl;dr answer

At this point, you probably have a fairly clear idea of how to reduce your ABC size.  If not:

1. a simple way it to take the conditional used for your `elsif` and place it in a helper method.
2. since you are assigning an `@` variable, and largely calling from one as well, your code uses no encapsulation of memory.  Thus, you can move both `if` and `elsif` block actions into each their own `load_search_users_by_role` and `load_search_users_by_order` methods.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation

Comment: @pangpang  You should use a 'bang' (`!`) at the end of the method name, like I wrote, as this is the ruby convention for when a method mutates data / state as a result of executing.  Also, thank you & glad

Comment: No, that is *not* the convention. The convention is that if and *only if* there are *two* methods which do the same thing, then the one which is more surprising is named with a bang. This has *nothing* to do with mutation (see e.g. `save` vs. `save!` in ActiveRecord or `exit` vs. `exit!` in Ruby) and it *only* applies when there are *two* methods (see e.g. about a dozen methods in `Array` or `String` or `Hash` which modify the receiver, yet don't have a bang.) There should only ever be a bang method if there is also a non-bang method with the same name.

Comment: @jorgwmittag I see you post lots of good things. I will take you at your word.

Comment: c2.com link is broken -- here's another good description: https://hub.codebeat.co/docs/software-quality-metrics#assignment-branch-condition